# How to put a background image in a figure using SCILAB?

Tags: scilab

In scilab in the listings of a figure does not show the option to set a background image. I would appreciate a person who has done that please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of Scilab actually have a `image` `style` for `uncontrol` objects. For example see [this sample](https://github.com/Foadsf/ScilabGUItuts/tree/master/Examples/Ex018) from Trity Technologies Sdn Bhd and Chin Luh Tan. Basically in the most simple form:

```
f = figure();
h = uicontrol(f, 'style', 'image', 'string',...
    get_absolute_file_path('foo.sce') + 'bar.png')
```

where `foo.sce` is your script's name and `bar.png` should be replaced by the relative address of the image you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know "built in" way to do that, but you can install the Image Processing Toolbox. After that you can read, process and display images. And if you plot something "over" the image, it becomes a background image :)

```
global IPD_PATH;
RGB=ReadImage(IPD_PATH+"demos\teaset.png");
//you can also call it with absolute path e.g.: "d:\pics\mypic.jpg"

scf(0);
ShowColorImage(RGB,"Color Image in the background");
//to see these axes set them visible (turned off by default in ShowColorImage)
//c=gca(); c.axes_visible=["on","on","off"];

a=newaxes();  //to use new axes, otherwise your axes go from 0 to the picture size in pixels
a.filled="off";   //to make it transparent

X=1:0.1:10;   //some arbitrary data to plot
plot2d(X,sin(X));
//since you dont know the index of the red colour in the current RGB color map, it's easier to do like this:
e=gce(); e.children.foreground=color("red");  
plot2d(X,cos(X));
e=gce(); e.children.foreground=color("blue");
```

Comment: Dear Attila, it is very appreciated to see that there are members of the community who try to help with their answer. Your help is highly appreciated. However this is the second post I see from you which in my humble opinion includes misleading information. Please consider updating it.